# Approximate algorithm for minimum raggedness word wrap

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, word-wrap

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm (ideally, C-like pseudocode) to give an approximate solution to the following partition problem. Given a sequence *S* = {*a_i* : *i*=1,...,*n*} and a bound *B*, determine a partition of *S* into some number *m* of contiguous subsequences as follows. For each *k*, let *s*_*k* be the sum of the elements of *k*-th subsequence. The partition must satisfy:

1. *s*_*k* ≤ *B* for each *k* (assume that the values of *B* and the *a*_*i* are such that this is always possible)
2. *m* is minimal (no smaller partition satisfies #1);
3. some measure of dispersion (for example, the variance or the maximum pair-wise difference among the *s*_*k*) is minimal among all partitions of size *m*.

I know that this is closely related to the [minimum raggedness word wrap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap). I am looking for something that can give a "good enough" solution for small values of *n* (less than 15) without pulling out heavy ammunition like dynamic programming, but also something a little faster than brute force.

Comment: So you want something between "minimum length" and "minimum raggedness"?

Comment: if you aim to minimize both `m` and the pairwise difference, i think you need to choose which one is priority

Comment: For such small values of _n_, will avoiding brute force pay off?

Comment: @Gabe - I guess that's right. Minimum length is too uneven, but I don't need minimum raggedness so I'd like to avoid the complexity.

Comment: @jon_darkstar - I guess that's right. The minimum raggedness algorithm doesn't explicitly minimize the number of lines; an extra line just adds another cost term. I guess I could live with extra lines if it really reduces raggedness.

Comment: @Michael - You may be right. I may have to fall back to that for now. But the problem may get an order of magnitude larger in the near future.

Comment: I do not consider dynamic programming "heavy ammunition"... I would estimate under 20 lines of code to implement the TeX algorithm from the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let S denote the sum of all the items and let n be the number of items. If you fit the items on m lines, you will have at least S/m weight on every line. Because S/m ≤ B, you get m ≥ S/B. I would start from ceiling(S/B) as the value of m and then increase m by one until a solution is found.

When m is set and n is given, it's just a matter of recursively searching for the correct boundaries. You guess the boundaries between lines one by one (recursively), and backtrack when solution becomes infeasible. If you find a solution, you store it for reference because it might be the best dispersion-wise. Eventually you choose the best solution. If there are no solutions, then you increase m by one and redo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a simple backtracking search. First I calculated *m* as described by antti.huima (that part was very easy and fixed *m*). I then allocated items greedily (packing each partition in order as much as possible). Finally I ran a backtracking algorithm to assign a delta to the start index for each partition boundary, *starting with the last partition*. Each delta_j represents how far back to move the start of partition *j* from the greedy start position. It's not hard to show that 0 <= delta_j < (size of partition j-1) for each j > 1 (otherwise the greedy algorithm would have behaved differently). This greatly cuts down on the search space as compared to a search to fill the partitions from 1 to *m*.

I suppose some sort of heuristic variant of this search is possible and would be more efficient, but I didn't try very hard to find one.